# GA Measurement Protocol batch limitations

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am working with the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol to track user interaction in my app. I am sending batched hits. For testing purposes I sent the batched hits to the validating endpoint. The syntax is correct, but I get the following error:

```
    {
        "messageType": "ERROR",
        "description": "The request size is larger than the maximum size supported by Google Analytics.",
        "messageCode": "VALUE_OUT_OF_BOUNDS"
    }
```

However, I am not exceeding the batch limitations as stated in the [GA docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#batch-limitations).
I am sending exactly 20 hits, which also get recognized by the API, and the entire payload has a size of roughly 8K byte.

Does anybody else faced these problems? Are the docs not up-to-date anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the docs seem to be out of date - I reduced max messages sent to 10 and it seems to work fine and I don't get these errors.